# Automatically save email with only start of folder name

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I have compiled this rule-triggered script to look for a reference number in an email ***`(DCSXXXX)`*** (using VBA in outlook) and to save this email in a folder with the same name.

However I am trying to find a way for the script to work in case the folder name is ***`"DCSXXX [any text]"`***, meaning that I only have the start of the folder name to work with. Any idea?

```
Public Sub GetValueUsingRegEx(myItem As MailItem)
' Set reference to VB Script library
' Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Reg1 As RegExp
    Dim colMatches As matchCollection
    Dim M1 As Match
    Dim Path As String
    Dim enviro As String
    Dim Match As String

    Path = "X:\Path"

    Set olMail = myItem

    Set Reg1 = New RegExp

    Reg1.IgnoreCase = True
    Reg1.Pattern = "DCS\d\d\d\d\d?"
    Reg1.Global = False

    If Reg1.test(olMail.Body) Then

        Set colMatches = Reg1.Execute(olMail.Body)
        Match = Reg1.Execute(olMail.Body)(0)

        For Each M1 In colMatches
            MsgBox (M1)
        Next

    End If

    Subject = olMail.Subject
    Subject = Replace(Subject, ":", "_")
    fullPath = (Path & "" & Match & "" & Subject & ".msg")

    olMail.SaveAs (fullPath)
    MsgBox fullPath
    MsgBox Match
    MsgBox Subject
    MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it always `DCS + 4 digits`?

Comment: Or five digits, that's why I thought Reg1.Pattern = "DCS\d\d\d\d\d?" would do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Get the full path before you save it, Here is quick example using [Dir Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dir-function)*

```
        Dim Path As String
            Path = "X:\Path\"

        Dim FldrName As String
            FldrName = Match

            On Error Resume Next
            Dim sGetPath As String
            sGetPath = Path & Match & "*"

            FldrName = Dir(sGetPath, vbDirectory)

        Dim SavePath As String
            SavePath = Path & FldrName & "\"
```

*Or use Function - Full Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example(Item As Outlook.mailitem)
    Dim Email As Outlook.mailitem
    Dim Matches As Variant
    Dim RegExp As New RegExp
    Dim Pattern As String

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.mailitem Then
        Pattern = "DCS\d\d\d\d\d?"
        With RegExp
            .Global = False
            .Pattern = Pattern
            .IgnoreCase = True
             Set Matches = .Execute(Item.Body)
        End With

        If Matches.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print Item.Subject ' Print on Immediate Window
            Debug.Print Matches(0)

            Dim Subject As String
                Subject = Item.Subject
                Subject = Replace(Subject, ":", "_")

            Dim Path As String
                Path = "C:\Temp\"

            Dim FldrName As String
                FldrName = Matches(0)

            Dim SavePath As String
                SavePath = FullPath(FldrName, Path)

                Debug.Print SavePath

            Item.SaveAs SavePath & Subject & ".msg", olMsg

        End If
    End If

    Set RegExp = Nothing
    Set Matches = Nothing
    Set Email = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function FullPath(ByVal FldrName As String, _
                                 ByVal Path As String)
    Dim sGetPath As String

    On Error Resume Next
    sGetPath = Path & FldrName & "*"

    Debug.Print sGetPath

    FldrName = Dir(sGetPath, vbDirectory)

    Do While Len(FldrName) > 0
        If Left(FldrName, 1) <> "" Then
            If (GetAttr(FldrName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                Debug.Print FldrName
                FullPath = Path & FldrName & "\"
                Debug.Print FullPath
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
        FldrName = Dir
    Loop

    If FullPath = Empty Then MsgBox "Folder Not Found"

End Function
```

Comment: Didn't think it would be so straightforward. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to strip off the excess text? You can use the Split function like this:

```
Subject = olMail.Subject
Subject = Replace(Subject, ":", "_")
Subject = Split(Subject, " ")(0)
```

That should give you just the `DCSXXX` part.

The `Split` function returns an `Array` using a `Delimiter`, in this case a space character. Putting a `(0)` directly after it makes it return a `String` equal to the first item in the `Array`

You could also simplify it to one line like this:

```
Subject = Split(Replace(olMail.Subject, ":", "_"), " ")(0)
```

But come to think of it, since `Split` would eliminate everything after the first space anyways, there is probably no need to use `Replace` to change the  `:` to `_`.... right?

```
Subject = Split(olMail.Subject, " ")(0)
```

Comment: Actually, I would like the email to be saved in a folder that starts with, let's say "DCS1234", regardless of what comes next. So if the folder was titled "DCS1234 Potatoes", or "DCS1234 John", the script should look for whichever folder starts with the reference code regardless of the following text and save there. Thanks!